# Octave urlread post

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, octave

I am trying to upload some data to a server by using a post request in octave. In the url I added the api-key, which should work. The question is how to include my postdata (which is a json object) and some headers. The docs on this function is limited but I try something like this:

```
param = {'headers','Accept: *','body',postData};
[response result] = urlread(url,'post',param);
```

Thusfar it gives a negative response. Is this how you should do this in Octave?

Comment: The third output of `urlread` is an error message. Did you check it?

Comment: it says     error = HTTP response code said error

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't set custom headers (such as Accept) using `urlread` or `urlwrite` in Octave.